# listening to button events inside a DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am trying to view some data inside a `DataList` with a template field button that deletes the values of the selected row. However, when I tested it, the delete button deletes all the values in the `DataList` not only the selected field. Here is my code. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
protected void Button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataListItem item in DataList2.Items)
    {
        Label post_IDLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("post_IDLabel");
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete_post", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        int post_ID = Convert.ToInt32(post_IDLabel.Text);
        string email = Session["email"].ToString();
        int course_ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["courseID"]);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@course_ID", course_ID));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@myemail", email));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@post_ID", post_ID));
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont see where you are getting the selected row?

you are just itterating through each row and firing off the delete method. So it will delete each item...

Comment: check my answer below... i dont really know what this DataList2 is. but I have suggested some solutions below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
protected void delete(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
    {
        if ((e.CommandName == "delete") && (e.CommandArgument != null))
        {
                string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString();
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete_post", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                int post_ID = (int) e.CommandArgument;
                string email = Session["email"].ToString();
                int course_ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["courseID"]);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@course_ID", course_ID));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@myemail", email));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@post_ID", post_ID));
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                DataList2.DataBind();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are iterating through the entire list of items in the datalist (using a foreach loop), so naturally all items will be affected.

I think the easiest way to do what you want is to handle DataList.ItemCommand event, and use a binding expression to pass a key value to your code.

Markup:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button12" runat="server" Text="Button" CommandName="MyDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MyId") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Code:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.CommandName == "MyDelete") && (e.CommandArgument != null))
    {
        //Add delete code here using e.CommandArgument to identify the correct record.
    }
}
```

Comment: whwat i said but using the actual property names :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like

```
var item = DataList2.Items.SelectedItem??
```

or if you can pass through some arguments within the sender of an id of the item you are looking for

```
Button btn = (Button)Sender;
int selectedItemId = int.parse(btn.Arguments["Someproperty"]);

var item = DataList2.Items.Single(i => i.Id == selectedItemId);
```

Comment: There is `DataList.SelectedItem`, but that property is related to the `Select` command being executed on one of the item, and is not very tightly tied to a button press on a particular row.  In other words, a different item can be the `SelectedItem` than the one in which you clicked the `Button`, unless you code everything exactly right (and you did not cover the particulars of that).  Either way, handling `DataList.ItemCommand` and using a binding expression on the `Button` is simpler and more robust in my opinion.